# Sequelize CLS transaction not used

Tags: transactions, sequelize.js

I'm trying implement a global transaction for all nested sequelize queries, using continuation local-storage support. I believe I've set namespace to Sequelize.cls correctly, because it works in many places as expected.

When migrating data from SQL server to Postgresql (sequelize models bonded), nested calls do not use the transaction. Code below.

```
var Steps = function() {

}

Steps.prototype = {
    constructor:Steps,
    IlIlce : function() {
        var connection = this.dataplex;
        var request = new sql.Request(connection);
        return request.execute('Migrasyon_Il').then(function (recordsets) {
            console.log('-=-=-=-=' + recordsets[0].length + ' İL kaydı bulundu');
            return Promise.reduce(recordsets[0], function (total, row) {
                return app.Sql.models.Il.create({
                    _Isim: row.AD,
                    _Entegrasyon: row.IL
                });
            }, 0);
        }).then(function (total) {
            return total;
        }).catch(function (cause) {
            throw cause;
        });
    }
    Step2 : function() {},
    Step3 : function() {},
    Step4 : function() {},
}
```

I've split migration steps into the the object prototype above. It is called in PostgreSQL/Sequelize transaction as below:

```
module.exports = {
    run: function() {
        var steps = new Steps();
        steps.dataplex = new sql.Connection(config);
        ...

        return steps.dataplex.connect().then(function() {
            // app.Sql => Sequelize instance.
            return app.Sql.transaction(function () { // <-- wrapper transaction
                return Promise.delay(1).then(function() {
                    return steps.IlIlce();
                }).then(function () {
                    return steps.Step2();
                }).then(function () {
                    return steps.Step3();
                }).then(function () {
                    return steps.Step4();
                    return true;
                });
            });
        }).then(function () {
            return true;
        }).catch(function (cause) {
            throw cause;
        }).finally(function() {
            steps.dataplex.close();
        });
```

None of the Sequelize methods in Steps functions use the wrapper transaction.

I've tried to debug it like:

- put a console.log() line in
  Transaction.prototype.prepareEnvironment() method, where it sets
  transaction in namespace. it passes.
- defined a beforeCreate() hook in Il model definition, which is used
  in Steps.prototype.IlIlce method. In this method context,
  Sequelize.cls.get('transaction') returns undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it's not related to sequelize.js at all. The cause of the problem is, the promise package that mssql is depended on does not carry context to it's callback function.